# Create a field with an default value toggle

Tags: ios, android

I've got an input field with a default value but I currently have the feeling no-one understands how it should be used.
The idea is if you toggle the switch on you use the default value and if you turn it off you can override this value.

Any suggestions how you could improve this? (I'm aware of the miss alignment)

Current implementation on android:

[image: Current implementation]

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a default value used in this way, and I certainly wouldn't consider it usable. Usually you would just place the default value in the text field, and then let the user change that value. If you're worried that the user might want to return to the default value, you could simply put a label *default: 17* next to the field.

Answer (score 2):

I'd remove the toggle as it is unnecessary and put the VAT in as it is, change the prompt underneath to something like "Type over the default rate to change it."

Answer (score 2):

To make it simpler, I would recommend:

- Having as default value 17%.
- In the case that the user changes, they can see the information message which states that the default value is 17%
- The label can be placed in different places, depending on your overall design.

[image: proposals]